# SAS: Difference between current_date and today functions

Tags: sas

I was wondering why there are two functions in SAS to achieve the same result. Current_date and today(). Is there is any difference between two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TODAY()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/p0hm9egy8s7mokn1mz0yxng80ax5.htm) is a base SAS function and works in any of the "normal" SAS contexts (including PROC SQL).

[`CURRENT_DATE()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0t7xulj9hno5an1891od2so3tyb.htm) is a FedSQL function.  FedSQL is new as of 9.4 and is basically a more-compatible version of SQL that includes data types found in other databases (like Hadoop, in particular) for core ANSI1999 compliance.  It is named differently because that is the name of the ANSI scalar function to return the current date.

Comment: Wow very nice info. Thank you Joe.